# How to code a side-nav menu with nested accordion with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm developing a website (Front-End: Bootstrap5, Back-End: PHP/MySQL).
I'm currently on the task of designing the Admin Interface.
So, I've retrieved an Admin Panel template from Bootstrap.
But I've tried to customize the side-nav menu with dropdown nested accordions when some of the dropdowns buttons opened all buttons at the same time.

I understand much of the code in the Admin Panel template.
But I just want the nested accordions to behave like a single-dropdown accordion when a button is cliked in the side-nav.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/accordion/#example

Comment: I'm sympathetic that you are a new developer, as we all were once.  Yet, everyone here donates their valuable time and in return we expect question askers to follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have identified the coding issue but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: aria-labelledby="..."

Comment: I know the coding issue is related to aria-labelledby="..." but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Or the coding issues with "id=collapseOne/Two/Three"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi guys, I had my problem solved by a Dev friend. It was an issue in the "id" of each "item" of the accordion. The issue was that all the dropdown items had the same "id". So, I just had to assign an "unique id" to each item.